# Getting data into Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am new to VS 2012, but have some MA Access and VB knowledge. I am preparing a project which needs to inherit some historical transaction data - too much to manually input. I want to import the data (either Excel 2010 or Access 2013 format) into an mdf Db of the App folder in VS 2012. Help there is no clear path on the forum and yet I can not believe that it is not possible to do this.

Steve C

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer your question - what format is your historical data in - is it in csv format, is it in the form of data carved on walls of caves, is it in excel sheet or whatever other form?

Comment: you can always import databases. please provide some specific information, what type of database are you trying to import in your visual studio project?

Comment: Hi new to this too.  The data is in Excel 2012 format, but can easily to converted to Access 2013 or CSV.